# Apache2, PHP 7.1, mod_rewrite, .htaccess 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, error-handling

Hi I seem to be having some issues with mod_rewrite.

.htaccess is rewriting urls from /welcome to /welcome.php ;

but they are returning 404 errors.

Apache2 
PHP 7.1
MySQL 5.8
mod_rewrite is enabled and loaded

Can someone please help I'm totally lost?

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#For removing extension as Options +MultiViews not working with RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9._@\-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/ profile.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^groups/([0-9]+)$ groups.php?grp=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^groups/ groups.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^view_post/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ view_post.php?post=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

#DirectoryIndex Options +Indexes

<FilesMatch ".(htaccess)">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#Options +MultiViews

IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>
```

Thats my .htaccess file.

Comment: try remove `RewriteBase /`

Comment: actually that broke it even more.

Comment: I fixed it. Just had to change back localhost in 000-default.conf in apache2.